# OCR image preprocessing with ImageMagick

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, ocr, tesseract, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to find the best way to clean the image with ImageMagick before I send it to tesseract.

So far the best result was give by this combination

```
convert test.tif -fill black -fuzz 30% +opaque "#FFFFFF" result.tif
```

This is the result image

[image: magick.exe]

It looks good but I need it to be better since tesseract still doesn't produce the best results.

How can I improve it?

This is how the images I am working on look.
[[image: example1][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/425XT.jpg)]
[[image: example2][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tQwh.jpg)]

Here are the original tif images.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jyrd58nbrava3j7/AAASaWBXYUk39oTJtAx4RRQRa?dl=0[!

Comment: Works pretty well for me, I get `238, Y= 514`

Comment: Which version of tesseract do you use? 3 or 4?

Comment: I am using 3 but will try 4 since its using deep learning.

Answer (score 0):

convert test.tif -negate -threshold 100 -negate result.tif

change threshold to high [my results was this on 100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7TKt.png)  or low according to your need. Hope it helps